# Very Slow Loading page in Huge Database MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a website with very huge MYSQL Database over 10 GB

All pages are working fine except just one page was very fast in the past but now its open in 30 minutes or more

I have backup for the files but the Database i don't have backup for it

Many developers and system administrators has studied the code and server performance and they are ensure that no problem in the code and the server

My question is why one page only in the admin affected by the large DB size or what the suggestion to be happened for this issue although the server scan didn't find any attacks

Finally : this page was loading very fast and this site was working very good since 2007 till 4-10-2018 no modification in any files happened no thing touched in files or DB ... Can you suggest what is the reason of that issue ??

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, there's no possible way to give you an answer, since there's no code, no details about the database, etc. Even the size of the database doesn't help, as 10GB, by today's standards, isn't "huge" (unless perhaps you're trying to run the database server on a very old, CPU- and memory-starved computer). Please edit your question to contain relevant code, SQL queries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from trying to rebuild indexes on the table(s) associated with the page, you also provide no code.

If not data / index related, what I would do is leave the original page alone, make a copy of it and somehow create an alternate link to bring up the SECOND instance of the page.   Then, on the second instance, I would remove all instances of actually querying the data components in case the page queries many things.  Then call up the second page. see if fast.  Then gradually bring back one populated query at a time to find the culprit.  Once that is done, fine-tune, confirm index(es), etc as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

There might be corrupted index. Try to rebuild them.

You can also enable `slow query log` to log queries which cause slowness. But it requires mysql server restart.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. We have no details *at all* about the problem space.